# What's your favorite tool, SDK or language to to access Rest APIs

Tags: api, rest

I have been looking into some Rest APIs for Open Data. There are many languages out there (most) that have reasonably easy to use programming constructs and APIs out there that you can use to access Rest APIs.

Do you have a preferred one?
Is there one with a highly convenient Rest API built in?
How do you adapt to custom formats and schema's being returned?
(Am I asking too many questions in one?)

What I have played with myself so far is basic C# (because I know this best) HTTP getters (HttpRestRequest/Response) and JsonSerializer with custom format classes. Pretty basic and very problem specific but it worked. But I write a lot of code that is not necessarily reusable for other problems.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) in single-user mode (no team/workspace). Postman is web based and my account follows me along my roaming habits across many PCs and devices.

A few similar questions were [asked previously on Softwarerecs.SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Brest%5D+is%3AQ)  and here is an answered one:
[Is there a decent REST API testing tool](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/71562/is-there-a-decent-rest-api-testing-tool-that-doesnt-lack-basic-features-or-gat) that doesn't lack basic features, or gate them behind a paywall?